# How can I track which software/process created or updated a Windows Sychronization Event Object?

Tags: windows, events

I have an application which sets a [Windows Synchronization Event Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682655(v=vs.85).aspx).  Recently I've seen indications that some *other* application may be setting/modifying that same object.  Is there a way I can audit these type of behavior?  I know Process Explorer can show me what the event object value is but I want to know what exactly set it to begin with.  Is there a tool for that? Process Monitor doesn't seem to trace it.